# ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)

Tags: python, jenkins-pipeline

I'm getting this error in the Jenkins build site stage when I'm trying to raise a pr, can anyone please help me resolve this error? Thanks in advance.

```
Build site
mkdocs build
— Shell Script
<1s
[2022-08-24T17:43:51.923Z] + mkdocs build
[2022-08-24T17:43:52.182Z] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2022-08-24T17:43:52.182Z]   File "/usr/local/bin/mkdocs", line 5, in <module>
[2022-08-24T17:43:52.182Z]     from mkdocs.__main__ import cli
[2022-08-24T17:43:52.182Z]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mkdocs/__main__.py", line 14, in <module>
[2022-08-24T17:43:52.182Z]     from mkdocs import config
[2022-08-24T17:43:52.182Z]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mkdocs/config/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
[2022-08-24T17:43:52.182Z]     from mkdocs.config.defaults import DEFAULT_SCHEMA
[2022-08-24T17:43:52.182Z]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mkdocs/config/defaults.py", line 4, in <module>
[2022-08-24T17:43:52.182Z]     from mkdocs.config import config_options
[2022-08-24T17:43:52.182Z]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mkdocs/config/config_options.py", line 5, in <module>
[2022-08-24T17:43:52.182Z]     from collections import Sequence, namedtuple
[2022-08-24T17:43:52.182Z] ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
script returned exit code 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With Python 3.10 `Sequence` has been moved to `collections.abc`.

Seems like you're using a very old version of mkdocs (from [Oct. 2020+](https://from%20collections.abc%20import%20Sequence)). Please consider updating mkdocs with `pip install -U mkdocs`.

Comment: Tried this, but it didn't work..

Comment: What version of mkdocs are you using ?

Comment: mkdocs --version
mkdocs, version 1.3.1 from c:\users\pooja\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\mkdocs (Python 3.8)

Comment: That's not the one you're using in your question.

Comment: That error occurred in a github repository, the error was already existing before I made changes to the repo, I want to resolve that error..

Comment: Your first example was run on Unix and Python 3.10, this one is from Windows and Python 3.8.
What do you mean a GitHub repo ? In a CI ? In that case, you have to upgrade mkdocs on your GitHub runner.

Comment: I have just added a picture of the error

Comment: Alright, so I guess mkdocs is not up-to-date in your runner. I don't know how you manage your runners, but maybe you can do this in the "Install pre reqs" for example.

Comment: Will this error - "ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections'" be solved if I update mkdocs?

Comment: I guess so, that's my answer to your question.