# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/var/lang/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, pip

I'm getting this error while executing my code in @aws lambda I'm trying to test my lambda function.

I tried updating my deployment package by updating **mkdocs** using pip install -u mkdocs and added as lambda layer as zip and also upgrading the python runtime to python3.11 and downgrade the python runtime to python3.7 and current runtime is python3.10. But still getting this error.

[image]

Comment: I gone through this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73491058/importerror-cannot-import-name-sequence-from-collections-usr-lib-python3) but didn't solved the error

Comment: because [`collections` doesn't have a `Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html).   Save yourself a lot of headache and get your lambda code running locally before shipping it to AWS Lambda

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69598162/7976758

Comment: tldr: `from collections.abc import Sequence`

Comment: It's also possible you need to update your `mkdocs` if that uses outdated `collecitons.Sequence`

Comment: Hi @erik258, I have done updating mkdocs but getting the same error again and also tried using "collections.abc import Sequence" but didn't worked.

Comment: Hi @phd , thank for the recommendation but it didn't worked out.

Comment: Is it related to the python version I am using ?
Cloud Shell default version of python is Python 2.7.18 and I am using virtual environment which have python version Python 3.7.16 and in the lambda runtime and lambda configuration I am using Python 3.10 .

Comment: But I tried downgrading the lambda runtime version to Python 3.7 then I got OpenSSL version error.

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproduction?  "that didn't work either" / "then I got a different error" if we don't see it, we can't help

Comment: Same error after implementing the solution @erik258 . Here is the Error  : 
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/var/lang/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": []
}

Comment: Clearly something is still importing it under `collections` directly.  Strange that the stack trace is empty